# AngularJS - Sorting Table Column using UnderScoreJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to click on Name  and want them to sort Ascending or Descending accordingly. I tried to $scope.listings = !$scope.listings in HTML ng-click and also tried making it true or false,  tried to write both functions in one but it doesn't work. I need a little help.

HTML

```
<th ng-click="setSort('Name')" style="width: 32%;"><h4>Name</h4></th>
```

JS

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$rootScope',
function ($rootScope) {
         $scope.setSort = function (sort) {
            $scope.resultsExist = false;
            if (sort) $scope.state.sortSpec = sort;
            if ($scope.state.sortSpec == 'Discount') {
                discountSort();
            }
            else if ($scope.state.sortSpec == 'Name') {
                nameSort();
            }
         };


          function nameSort() {
              $scope.listings = _.sortBy($scope.listings, function (listing) {
              return listing['name'];
              });
          }
          function reverseSort() {
              $scope.listings = _.sortBy($scope.listings, function (listing) {
              return listing['name'].charCodeAt('name') * -1;
              });
          }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an array with data:

```
$scope.data = [
  {name: 'John', surname: 'Smith'},
  {name: 'Mary', surname: 'Andrews'},
  {name: 'Ian', surname: 'Pitus'}
];
```

Showing in a simple html table as:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th><span class="sortable" ng-click="sortDataBy('name')">Name</span></th>
    <th><span class="sortable" ng-click="sortDataBy('surname')">Surname</span></th> 
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="record in data">
    <td>{{record.name}}</td>
    <td>{{record.surname}}</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

And keeping you current sort attributes (field and order) in a simple object:

```
$scope.sortAttrs = {
  field: null,
  order: null
};
```

Simply implement `sortDataBy` function as:

```
$scope.sortDataBy = function(field) {
  $scope.sortAttrs.field = field;
  $scope.sortAttrs.order = $scope.sortAttrs.order == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
  var sortDataAsc = _.sortBy($scope.data, function(o) { 
    return o[field];
  });
  $scope.data = $scope.sortAttrs.order == 'asc' ? sortDataAsc : sortDataAsc.reverse();
};
```

You can take a look in the above implementation in [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SS7D9ayXeqSeUfwaXTxt?p=preview).

Adding more fields like "discount" etc. is simple enough. Just add data for fields in `$scope.data` array and new column in `html table`.